# Recursive logging from KafkaAppender on level INFO

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

The documentation says to avoid recursive logging do not let write org.apache.kafka log on DEBUG level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ...
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO" /> <!-- avoid recursive logging -->
  </Loggers>
```

However, in this case, org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata logs ClusterID on level INFO, which leads to recursive logging and WARN log

```
kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 WARN Recursive logging from [org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata] for appender [KafkaAppender1].
```

Does this mean that need to set org.apache.kafka level warn?

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that you should configure your org.apache.kafka Logger to send log events to some other Appender. All the logging level does is prevent log events from being logged at all. If you want to just prevent ALL Kafka log events then set its logger level to OFF.